# Unit test for method that calls other method of different class

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, sharedpreferences

I want to unit test a method using mockito, which calls other other method of different class and that other method contain some shared preference operation .

This is the method I want to test

```
public boolean isPersonAvailable(Context context) {
    Person person = new Person();
    return person.loadPerson(context)!= null;
}
```

Here is the structure of my Person class and that Person class depends on another method of another class

```
class Person{
    public  Person loadPerson(Context context) {
        SharedPreferenceProvider sp = new SharedPreferenceProvider();
        sp.read(context,"any key");
        return new User;
    }
}
```

Here is the structure of my SharedPreferenceProvider class

```
class SharedPreferenceProvider{

       public  String read(Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences preference = context.getSharedPreferences("AppID", AppConstants.SAVE_MODE);
        return preference.getString(key, EMPTY_STRING);
    }

}
```

How can unit test such method which has so many dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that your method under test does `new Person()`.

Basically that impacts your ability to do reasonable unit testing. You can either work around that design deficiency by using PowerMock(ito) or JMockit, or you improve your design by avoiding that call. In other words: read about dependency injection. As that would allow you to already have some Person object available. And then you could simply *mock* that object in advance, and have its method return whatever you need for reasonable testing.

Your code under test has only *one* dependency, to a Person object. Get rid of that (by enabling your code to interact with mocked Person object), and your problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

With unit-testing you try to find bugs in the isolated code.  The method `isPersonAvailable`, however, consists purely of interactions with other classes like `Context` and `Person`.  If there are bugs in this method, they will lie on the level of interactions with these other classes: Are you calling the right constructor of `Person`?  Is a return value of `null` from `person.loadPerson` really an indication that the person is not available, or is this signaled in a different way?

You will never find such interaction bugs with mocks: If you have misunderstood the way the other classes work, you will implement the mocks according to your own wrong understanding.  Therefore, a method like `isPersonAvailable` should be tested with integration testing rather than with unit-testing.

That said, even if it is not of much relevance for this particular method, the recommendation to learn about "dependency injection" is certainly good.  You may also find it valuable to look for "inversion of control".